# System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException after publishing xbap

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, publish, xbap

recently i've started learning C# and encountered a problem with my WPF application after publishing it.

First, let me explain what the application should do: Read the xml-file "testxml.xml", and write the names given there in a ListBox. The xml-File lies in \myProject\bin\Debug.

My code:

```
public partial class Page1 : Page
        {
        private string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\testxml.xml";
        List myList = new List();
```

`public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ReadXML(path, myList,ListBox1);
    }


    public static void ReadXML(string path, List<TestXML> myList, ListBox ListBox)
    {
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<TestXML>));
            TextReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
            object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
            myList = (List<TestXML>) obj;
            reader.Close();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < myList.Count; i++)
        {
            ListBox.Items.Add(myList[i].Name);
        }

    }

}`

This works fine in debug mode. 
So, I tried to publish it. Therefore, I've included the xml-file in my project and changed its settings "Build Action" to "Content" and "Change to Output Directory" to "Copy Always". Furthermore, I changed its "Publish Status" from "Data File" to "Include" in my project properties. I published it via publish wizard to "C:\user\" and select "From a CD-ROM or DVD-ROM".

This gave me an xbap-File and an "Application Files"-Folder in "C:\users\". The xml-file is available under "\Application Files\MyProject_1_0_0_x\bin\Debug". But when I execute the xbap-File, it gives me a huge error that starts with

"System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."

My suggestion so far is the directory of the xml-file, which perhaps doesn't work after publishing. What would be the correct directory?
Or is there another mistake I'm not aware of?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: TargetInvocationException masks the real exception by telling you that it crashed during "a method invocation". If you want more information, try to look at the InnerException, it should tell you what exactly caused the crash.

Comment: Do you mean the line directly under it?
`System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type "System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" failed`

Comment: It seems the issue is with XBAP trust level, not with anything in your code. Try either setting the level from your project settings (read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/security-wpf)). Another possibility is to try running the xbap using 'Run as Administrator' and seeing if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've changed it to "full trust application" and the error is gone now, fantastic. Nevertheless, the ListBox is empty, there seems to be a problem with the xml-file path.

Comment: To debug that, you could add a `MessageBox.Show(path);` or some way of displaying the path so you can at least see where it's looking, and change `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\testxml.xml";` accordingly. Another (perhaps not what you require) possible solution is to have users pick the file using [OpenFileDialog](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/openfiledialog-in-C-Sharp/).

Comment: Tried your idea with the Messagebox and the path is indeed very far away from what I need (C:\Users\me\AppData\LocalApps\2.0\.....). It should be the path where he put the xbap-file or the "Application Files"-Folder.

Comment: Try building in Release instead of Debug and see if code runs in VS.  Next try to run from project bin folder by double clicking on the exe file.  Usually changing project settings to Any CPU and/or X86 sometimes solves these issues.